# How do I make a directory?

Tags: command-line

How can I make a directory on the desktop? 
I tried `cd /desktop` command but it gives an error  `no such file or directory`.

What's the correct command?

Comment: try to run `cd ~/Desktop` instead of `cd /desktop`. Do you see the difference? Capital "D" makes difference.

Comment: please provide the results of `ls ~` into your question.

Answer (score 7):

From command line

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir yes
```

will make a directory named "yes" inside your current user's "Desktop". It will almost instantly show up on your desktop.

You can also do

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/yes
```

---

In case of language other than English where the directories are named into another language this is a more generic way:

```
source $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs
cd $XDG_DESKTOP_DIR
mkdir yes
```

or

```
source $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs
mdir $XDG_DESKTOP_DIR/yes
```

Comment: It is not working

Comment: If your Ubuntu language is not English, then the folder 'Desktop' will have a different name. You can see its name either in the file browser or by typing `ls` in the terminal (if you are located in your home directory).

Comment: what do you mean "not working"? what have you typed and what's the error?

Comment: @vandit and we need to guess what is not working?

Answer (score 5):

The command to make a directory is `mkdir 'Directory name'` , `cd 'Directory name'` is the command used to go inside an **existing** directory.