# What are the commands needed to create a folder in your user's documents folder if you are currently in the home folder? (using LINUX command line)

Tags: command-line

please include the command that would be used in LINUX

Comment: Not sure if this is a homework question but I've given you the benefit of the doubt and answered it!

Comment: Your question seems to be implicitly assuming that the Documents folder is in your home folder (which it needn't be - you can configure the location using XDG directory settings).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cd into a directory in the home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262674/) and [How do I make a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/725882/)

Answer (score 1):

You can move to the Documents folder first then create a directory:

```
cd ~/Documents
mkdir mynewdirectory
```

or you can do it all with absolute paths from wherever you are in your system:

```
mkdir ~/Documents/mymnewdirectory
```

(The `~` is a shortcut for your home directory, in which your Documents directory resides).

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p ~/Documents/newfolder/name/that/can/be/as/long/as/you/want
```

the `-p` flag lets you make multiple new directories all at once